# Adding an item to an indexed property - PropertyChangeSupport

Tags: java, javabeans, propertychangelistener

I am currently working with PropertyChangeListeners and I want to know if it would be advisable to fire a property change whenever an object is added (or removed, for that matter) to an indexed property such as an ArrayList.

```
public class SimpleBean implements Serializable
{
   private ArrayList<Matrix> mats;
   private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

   public SimpleBean()
   {...}

   public void addMat(Matrix m)
   {
      pcs.firePropertyChange("mats", null, m); // I'm having trouble with the parameters
      mats.add(m);
   }

}
```

I was reading the PropertyChangeListener tutorials and it seemed like it was appropriate to fire a property change whenever the value of a bound property changed. Well, I wasn't quite sure if this meant that I should fire a property change whenever a property was modified by *any* means or only when the property (or an element of that property) was strictly set/reassigned to a different value.

In my program, it would be very convenient if several classes could change every time an element is removed from or added to the mats ArrayList, and I figured that a PropertyChangeListener could help me in that regard.

Please let me know if this method is not recommended and if there is another way that other classes can listen and respond to deletion/addition to indexed properties.

Comment: Looking at the contract, you are expected to send `mats` before modification and `mats` after modification. I doubt that is what you want. You may want to use `fireIndexedPropertyChange` rather.

Comment: Okay, but if I try fireIndexedPropertyChange, would `pcs.fireIndexedPropertyChange("mat", mats.size(), null, m)` be a suitable replacement? Since everything I have learned about changing bound properties has to do with assigning a property to something different as opposed to adding onto/removing from it, I have trouble parameterizing this method. @KDM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following example:

```
public class SimpleBean implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Matrix> mats;
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void setMats(ArrayList<Matrix> mats) {
        if(mats.equals(this.mats))
            return;
        ArrayList<Matrix> oldMats = this.mats ;
        this.mats = mats ;
        pcs.firePropertyChange("mats", oldMats, mats);
    }

    public ArrayList<Matrix> getMats() {
        return mats;
    }

    public void setMat(int index, Matrix mat) {
        Matrix existing = index == mats.size() ? null : mats.get(index);
        if(existing.equals(mat))
            return;
        mats.remove(index);
        mats.add(index, mat);
        pcs.fireIndexedPropertyChange("mats", index, existing, mat);
    }

    public Matrix getMat(int index) {
        return mats.get(index);
    }

    public void addMat(Matrix m) {
        setMat(mats.size(), m);
    }

}
```

Which implements both propertyChange as well as indexedPropertyChange for `mats`.

Comment: In your `setMat` method, if `index` = `mats.size()`, then wouldn't `mats.remove(index)` cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? Not only that, since `existing` would be set to `null`, wouldn't `existing.equals(mat)` cause a `NullPointerException`? @KDM

Comment: I am concentrating more on the contract of Java bean, rather than the runtime errors. Just add the guard for the special case of adding to the end of the list and you are set.

Comment: I see. Well I'll try to implement it myself. Also, thanks for the answer.